# How do I get crond to autostart on Alpine in a Docker container?

Tags: docker-compose, cron, alpine-linux

I want to be able to run a simple bash script within a container service on the hour using cron. I'm using Alpine Linux via `docker-compose` with a custom Dockerfile to produce a php-fpm based image, on which I hope to get `crond` running as well - except I can't.

Executing `ps aux | grep cron` on the container once built, returns nothing.

From what I understand, the usual Linux startup processes don't exist in Docker containers - fine - so how *do I* auto-start `crond`? Its dirs under `/etc/periodic/` are created automatically, so I don't understand why the applicable process that consumes those dirs, isn't also running.

I tried creating a dedicated service definition within `docker-compose.yml`, which actually worked but the shell script to be run hourly needs access to a php binary which is running in a *different* container, so this isn't a viable solution.

If I shell into the container and run `rc-service crond start` I get this - but it never "finishes":

```
/var/www/html # rc-service crond start
 * WARNING: crond is already starting
```

```
#> docker --version
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
#> docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01
```

I need a solution that I can place into my `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml` files.

Dockerd is running on Ubuntu Xenial FWIW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to run a cronjob container (Alpine), you need to make sure sure that the command of your docker container is

```
exec crond -f
```

if you want to add this to a docker file

```
CMD ["exec", "crond", "-f"]
```

you also may need to update the corn files before running the above command

## Update based on the docker file and compose

To be able to solve your issues you need to update your docker-compose to have two containers one for cron and one for web

```
 service_php_cron:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/services/php/Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: base_service_php
    command: 'cron_jobs'
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/public
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    # Low level container logging
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "1m"
        max-file: "5"

  service_php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/services/php/Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    command: 'web_server'
    container_name: base_service_php
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/public
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    # Low level container logging
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "1m"
        max-file: "5"
```

you also need to update your docker file to be able to handle multiple commands using docker entry points

Add the below line to your docker file + remove the CMD one

```
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod a+x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

and finally, create the entry point (make sure it hash execute permissions)

```
#!/bin/sh -e

case $1 in

  web_server)
    YOUR WEB SERVER COMMAND 
  ;;

  cron_jobs)
     exec crond -f
  ;;

  *)
    exec "$@"
  ;;

esac

exit 0
```

you can check this link for more info about [entrypoints](https://medium.com/swlh/five-use-cases-for-docker-entry-points-a5eb6661dac6)

Comment: This answer appears to refer to calling the `crond` executable via a CLI command. I'm specifically seeking a solution that can be added as line(s) within my Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml files.

I have edited my question to make this clearer. Many thanks.

Comment: you can use the command also from the docker file or compose, I updated the answer with an example for docker file. can you update the question with your docker file and compose ?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my `Dockerfile` with that, but as I suspected, `CMD` becomes the first (only?) command that is run on container startup, meaning the base image my `Dockerfile` is built on, isn't able to run _its own_ default command (starting php-fpm).


Dockerfile: https://gist.github.com/dcentrica/60804132381302b587f4c65e09e2c576
docker-compose snippet: https://gist.github.com/dcentrica/efcea99ab567c44cd9dd33e9acf939a8

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! This works. I hadn't thought of service-definition duplication in `docker-compose.yml` and also +1 for the `command` YML option.